# Get installation path of specific application in my machine

Tags: c#, path, installation

I'm trying to get the installation path of winrar (if someone installs it on C:\users\admin\ for example) within my application using C#, I found this method:

http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1995.htm

It works for many programs, but it didn't work for winrar. Does anybody know how?? Thanks!!

Comment: Does that method not work because WinRAR's installer is not putting uninstall information in the normal place in the registry?  Have you done a registry search to see if the information is anywhere else in the registry you could pick up?

Comment: Do you run your application on 64 bit windows?

Answer (score 1):

```
string GetPath(string extension)
{
    var appName = (string)Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(extension).GetValue(null);
    var openWith = (string)Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(appName + @"\shell\open\command").GetValue(null);
    var appPath =  System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(openWith, "[a-zA-Z0-9:,\\\\\\. ]+").Value.Trim();
    return new FileInfo(appPath).Directory.FullName;
}
GetPath(".rar");
```